# Why are PCIe Completion Timeouts specified as ranges?

Tags: pcie

The PCI Express Base Specification specifies four ranges of completion timeouts:

```
  A:  50 us -  10 ms
  B:  10 ms - 250 ms
  C: 250 ms -   4 s
  D:   4 s  -  64 s
```

The Device Control Register 2 allows a specific subrange to be configured by the firmware.

Why are the timeouts specified as ranges? 50 us to 10 ms is several orders of magnitude -- how can firmware know which timeout value from the range is being used by the hardware?

Comment: Drivers are written specifically for the device aren't they?

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. If the driver sets the Device Control Register 2 to 0x0001 to select the "50 us – 100 us" range, what is the actual completion timeout value? 50 us? 100 us? Any random value in the range?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of this PCI Express Base specification, but it seems to me that it basically works like every other bus protocol:

If you specify a timeout range in your driver, this does mean that the master or slave device must be able to meet this timeout. So a configured 50us to 10ms timeout means that "something" must react within this range or the protocol will fail.

I try to explain it by another "real-life" example: The timetable for bus A says the bus is leaving between 8-12 a.m. and the timetable for bus B says this one is leaving between 9-11 a.m. You must decide which bus you want to take (driver configuration), but you will not be able to tell exactly when each of the busses A or B leave.

Comment: Thanks, though I don't recall ever seeing a bus timetable that specifies a range of departure times. In my experience, the bus leaves at such and such time, and if you're not there, you're taking the next one. Likewise, I've never seen a timeout specified as a range. Why not just quote the high end of the range? Or is the specification overly general to accommodate a wider variety of hardware, such that some PCIe endpoints will time out after 50 us and others will timeout after 10 ms?

Comment: Yes, the bus example is a bit far off reality. Some timeouts must be a range because there is a MIN value that must also be satisfied. I.e. something is not allowed to react too soon.

Answer (score 0):

50us is where the PCI requests will generally be completed but host PCI controller will not raise the completion timeout error untill 10ms have passed. Between 50us and 10mns, Host controller can do retries etc.

Comment: Understood, I'm just wondering why the _timeout_ is specified as a _range_.